# how can I calculate the distance between points using numpy

Tags: python

```
i = np.array([[ -1, 2],
              [1, 2],
              [ 0, 0]])

a = np.array([[0, 2, sqrt(5)],
              [2, 0, sqrt(5)],
              [sqrt(5), sqrt(5), 0]])
```

Each row of `i` is coordinates for a point in the format of `(x,y)`. `a` is the distance matrix between each point. How can I get the distance matrix using `numpy`?

Answer (score 4):

Use [pdist](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.pdist.html):

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.spatial.distance import pdist, squareform

i = np.array([[ -1, 2],
              [1, 2],
              [ 0, 0]])

result = squareform(pdist(i))

print(result)
```

**Output**

```
[[0.         2.         2.23606798]
 [2.         0.         2.23606798]
 [2.23606798 2.23606798 0.        ]]
```